# Generating Functions with Functions

Tags: python, function, arguments, argument-passing

Yes, I want to generate functions using functions.

I have hit a wall at how to cleanly get function1 to pass arguments into a function2 (which is defined in function1).

```
def function1(*args):
    def function2(*args):
        print "I will do some stuff or whatever"

    return function2

new_function = function1()

new_function()
------->I will do some stuff or whatever
```

Anyway, I can't wrap my head around how I can pass new arguments into function2 and then consequently new_function by using function1.

In short, I want to be able to do this:

```
new_function = function1(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

And have arg1, arg2, and arg3 pass into new_function but I can't get the structure right.

Comment: What you are writing is a decorator, try this: [Python decorators in 12 easy steps](http://simeonfranklin.com/blog/2012/jul/1/python-decorators-in-12-steps/)

Comment: @BurhanKhalid Such a function could be used as a decorator (and indeed that's the simplest way to make decorators), but OP hasn't shown any interest in applying the decorator syntax. That said, this tutorial is still applicable and useful here. :) (In particular, decoration involves passing a function into the outer `function1` as an argument, which is a whole other conceptual level that OP might struggle with.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give `function1`'s parameters different names, and then just use them inside the `function2` definition:

```
def division_factory(quotient):
    def divide(divisor):
        return divmod(quotient, divisor)
    return divide

divide_81_by = division_factory(81)
divide_81_by(3) # (27, 0)
```

Comment: is divmod a typo? You are returning it but it appears to not have been defined.

Comment: `divmod` is a Python builtin. I chose it more or less arbitrarily for demo purposes.